# Show a progressbar in taskbar what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, taskbar

Following  my previous post iam trying to make this work

I have the following code (Edited):

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
   ...
   private TaskDialog Taskbar = new TaskDialog();
 }

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Taskbar.ProgressBar.Value = progressBar1.Value;
    }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

 bgWorker_dowork()
 {
   timer1.Enabled = true;
      timer1.Start();

      while(progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum)
      {
        progressBar1.Value++;
      } 
  }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Edit: i cant make it show a progressbar while minimized on the taskbar, althought i did the changes suggested..

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're blocking your GUI thread

```
  while(true)
  {
    progressBar1.Value++;
  }
```

This will cause it to lock and prevent it from updating the UI.

Never run such loops on your main thread, use a `BackGroundWorker` for stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the value of the Progress Bar should not exceed the Maximum Value.

[ProgressBar.Maximum Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx)

[ProgressBar.Minimum Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.minimum.aspx)

```
 while (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum) 
 { 
       progressBar1.Value++; 
       Application.DoEvents();//This will update the UI paintings 
                              //which is not happening prior to this code.     
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to downvote your answer, but please correct `while` part, because is wrong...

Comment: Thanks for the knowkedge sharing. Thanks again. i hope this will be helpful in future now.

Comment: although i made the changes as instructed i have no change.